# Logic: Number x is a square of a prime number. Difference between conjunction and implication

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Number x is a square of a prime number

Is there some difference if do that it like this:

$∃_{p}$$[(∀_{n∊N} $ $ n|p ⇒ n=p $ v $ n=1) ⋀ (p\neq1)] ⇒ x = p*p$

or

$∃_{p}$$[(∀_{n∊N} $ $ n|p ⇒ n=p $ v $ n=1) ⋀ (p\neq1)] ⋀ x = p*p$

And if there is, when i should use implication and when conjunction in tasks like this one.

Comment: The first version is all wrong. The second version is also wrong but could be made right by moving the $]$ all the way to the right end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting an implication directly under an $\exists$ is almost always wrong.

Here your first attempt says

> There is some $p$ such that **if** $p$ is a prime, **then** $x$ is its square.

And that is always true, no matter what $x$ it -- namely, you can just set $p$ to be $4$. Since $4$ is not a prime, the implication is automatically true, and that single example is enough to make the $\exists$ true.

The second attempt is much better (though bof may or may not be right when he thinks your bracketing is off; depends on your conventions for how tightly quantifiers bind syntactically):

> There is a $p$ such that $p$ is a prime **and** $x$ is its square.

---

On the other hand for $\forall$ you would typically use an implication under the quantifier to limit which possible values you're interested in.  As before, the implication will be automatically *true* when the condition is not satisfied, and for $\forall$ it is the *true* case that does not influence the truth value of the entire $\forall$ formula.